# Django timedelta (DurationField) to seconds

Tags: python, django, django-models, momentjs, timedelta

How to convert a timedelta to seconds in Django?

I have a Django backed serving an API which at some point returns a calculated field:

```
enhanced_client = client.objects.annotate(duration=ExpressionWrapper((F('end_time')-F('start_time')), output_field=DurationField()))
```

with the following value (timedelta):

```
P0DT00H02M00.102730S
```

How can I turn this into seconds in javascript? I'm also using moment js but I can't parse this at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) and [`asSeconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/) getter

> To get the number of seconds in a duration, use `moment.duration().seconds()`.
>
> It will return a number between 0 and 59.
>
> f you want the length of the duration in seconds, use `moment.duration().asSeconds()` instead.

```js
var input = 'P0DT00H02M00.102730S';
console.log( moment.duration(input).asSeconds() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there any way to pass this through `humanize` as well? Or at least round it up?

Comment: Well... this seems to work. `moment.duration(moment.duration(input).asSeconds(), 'seconds').humanize()`